# Trying to use Tesseract and OpenCV with Emscripten in CMake project results in multiple "error: undefined symbol ...."

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, tesseract, emscripten

My project used to work fine without emscripten [github project](https://github.com/AlejandroCamba/screenshot-to-text-converter), Then when migrating it it to work with emscripten i first created an initial project without any libraries to see if it worked and it did, i was able to use the c++ test code in the browser but then when i tried to use external libraries (tesseract, opencv) i get when compiling the following code:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/imgToTxt.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/imgToTxt.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgToTxt.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/user/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/em++  -DTESS_IMPORTS @CMakeFiles/imgToTxt.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall","cwrap"]' -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall","cwrap"]' -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_extractTextFromImage"]' -std=c++11 -O3 -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/imgToTxt.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/imgToTxt/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../public/imgToTxt.wasm.js
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv11_InputArrayC1ERKNS_7MatExprE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: Link with `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
warning: __ZN2cv11_InputArrayC1ERKNS_7MatExprE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv17adaptiveThresholdERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEdiiid (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv17adaptiveThresholdERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEdiiid may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat8copySizeERKS0_ (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv3Mat8copySizeERKS0_ may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv5erodeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES2_NS_6Point_IiEEiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv5erodeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES2_NS_6Point_IiEEiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6dilateERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES2_NS_6Point_IiEEiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv6dilateERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES2_NS_6Point_IiEEiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEi (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEi may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6resizeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv6resizeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7inRangeERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_S2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv7inRangeERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_S2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8cvtColorERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEii (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv8cvtColorERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEii may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv9rectangleERKNS_17_InputOutputArrayENS_5Rect_IiEERKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiii (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cv9rectangleERKNS_17_InputOutputArrayENS_5Rect_IiEERKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiii may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cvcoERKNS_3MatE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN2cvcoERKNS_3MatE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI11GetUTF8TextEv (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI11GetUTF8TextEv may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI4InitEPKcS2_NS_13OcrEngineModeEPPciPK13GenericVectorI6STRINGESA_b (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI4InitEPKcS2_NS_13OcrEngineModeEPPciPK13GenericVectorI6STRINGESA_b may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI8SetImageEPKhiiii (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI8SetImageEPKhiiii may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI9RecognizeEP10ETEXT_DESC (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI9RecognizeEP10ETEXT_DESC may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPIC1Ev (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPIC1Ev may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPID1Ev (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPID1Ev may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
em++: error: '/home/user/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node /home/user//emsdk/upstream/emscripten/src/compiler.js /var/folders/8l/yxqfn7ss44qbx_mfnp142v800000gn/T/tmp113_4h4_.txt' failed (1)
make[2]: *** [../public/imgToTxt.wasm.js] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/imgToTxt.dir/all] Error 2
```

My CMakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
option(JS_ONLY "Compiles to native JS (No WASM)" OFF)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/home/user/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake")

set(Leptonica_DIR "/home/user/leptonica/build")
set(Tesseract_DIR "/home/user/tesseract/build")
set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/user/build_opencv")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

project(imgToTxt VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/public)

find_package(OpenCV)
find_package(Leptonica REQUIRED)
find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Leptonica_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)

add_definitions("-std=c++11 -O3")
include_directories(include)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".html")


add_executable(imgToTxt ${SOURCES})

if(JS_ONLY)
    message(STATUS "Setting compilation target to native JavaScript")
    set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".js")
    set_target_properties(imgToTxt PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-s WASM=0 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[_extractTextFromImage]'")
else(JS_ONLY)
    message(STATUS "Setting compilation target to WASM")
    set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".wasm.js")
    set_target_properties(imgToTxt PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-s WASM=1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[_extractTextFromImage]'")
endif(JS_ONLY)

target_link_libraries(imgToTxt ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(imgToTxt ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

include(CPack)
```

i run the project with

> cmake
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake
> ..

and then **make**.

I feel i'm missing something i should be doing with libraries to be able to compile them but i can't figure out what exactly.. If you'd like me to add anything that helps clarify my question let me know in the comments.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Deleted build folder and ran cmake, output:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:45 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:48 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:55 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:62 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:69 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:76 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:83 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:90 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:97 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:104 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:111 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:118 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:125 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:132 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:139 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/build_opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found OpenCV: /home/user/build_opencv (found version "4.4.0") 
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/tesseract/build/TesseractTargets.cmake:45 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/tesseract/build/TesseractConfig.cmake:22 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Setting compilation target to WASM
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/imgToTxt/build
```

Comment: try adding this line `target_link_libraries(imgToTxt ${OpenCV_LIBS}` in CmakeLists.txt

Comment: @zteffi it's already there! at the end, should i put it somewhere else? i have both ```target_link_libraries(imgToTxt ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES})``` and ```target_link_libraries(imgToTxt ${OpenCV_LIBS})```

Comment: Hm your CMakeLists.txt looks correct. Could you please try to remove the CMakeCache.txt from your build folder and rerun the cmake command? Posting the output from the cmake command could be helpful.

Comment: @MatzZze Sure i editted the question, cmake output is there now! Thank you for your time

Comment: Probably you have to add the mentioned undefined symbols also to the `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`. Every undefined symbol message says:"[...] may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library"

Comment: @MatzZze i'll try to do that to see if it works, thank you!